# ¿Qué es [{x:y}={x:x}] = [] en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Un amigo me pasó este fragmento por mail y no puedo entender qué es lo que sucede. Me estoy volviendo loco.

```js
var x = 'valor',
    y = 'inicial';    
console.log(x,y);

[{x:y}={x:x}] = [];
console.log(x,y);

[{x:y}={x:x}] = [{}];
console.log(x,y);
```

Al ejecutarlo, imprime:

```
valor inicial
valor valor
valor undefined
```

Me pregunto:

1. ¿Cómo es que a `y` se le asignó el valor de `x`?
2. ¿Por qué pasa a ser `undefined` si solamente se cambió el array vacío `[]` por el array con un objeto vacío `[{}]`?
3. ¿Cómo se llama esto? ¿Qué concepto sería? Quiero leer de qué se trata pero no sé cómo buscarlo.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Muchas gracias @EduenSarceño! Es eso!.. Entendí el punto de mi 1ra pregunta. Todavía no termino de descifrar el 2do, pero ya tengo cómo buscarlo :)

Comment: Propongo que dejes aquí solamente la pregunta 3 y que @EduenSarceño proporcione una breve respuesta indicando de qué se trata. Si te surgen dudas, plantéalas en otras preguntas, el formato del sitio exige que haya una pregunta por problema. Tal como está ahora tu pregunta podría ser cerrada como demasiado amplia. En cambio, preguntando solamente por el punto 3, la respuesta podría ser útil a otras personas.

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación @A.Cedano. No obstante, me parece que las 3 preguntas están apuntando a exactamente lo mismo: explicar el fragmento de código. Realmente no estoy de acuerdo en que pedir explicaciones sobre un fragmento de código de 2 líneas sea demasiado amplio. Con todo respeto, no voy a seguir la recomendación.

Comment: Como tú prefieras. Tal como está la pregunta sólo es útil para ti. Y me parece que analizarle código al otro no es el objetivo de este sitio, sino responder a dudas concretas. Ya tienes el enlace que te explica de qué se trata. Ahora te toca a ti analizar el código y si tienes dudas, lo correcto sería plantear otra pregunta con **esa duda que surja**. Al final, la comunidad decidirá mediante votos si la pregunta es amplia o no. Yo particularmente la considero amplia, y la votaré para cierre. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano Como mencioné antes, luego de leer la documentación en MDN, aún no termino de comprenderlo completamente, pero estás en total libertad de votar lo que quieras. Ya me había quedado claro con tu primer comentario. Por lo que vengo leyendo hasta ahora, creo que es un concepto más que interesante y muy útil, por lo que dudo que sólo sea útil para mi. Probablemente pueda cambiarle el título a "*Qué es la asignación por destructuring*", de modo que sea mucho más útil para otros, y lo hubiese hecho si hubiese sabido... todavía estoy entendiendo el tema.